# Example of parser with loop invariant code motion

Tags: loops, optimization, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I'm learning how to make a mini compiler using flex and bison. Right now I'm interested in loop optimizations, especially the loop invariant code motion. Has anyone written a parser with the implemented optimization or maybe seen it somewhere? I'd like to see an example of how it's written in the code.

Comment: Probably not too helpful, but you can find the LLVM implementation [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/lib/Transforms/Scalar/GVNHoist.cpp).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project on flex and bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854563/project-on-flex-and-bison)

Comment: You will find useful material in my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854563/project-on-flex-and-bison

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I've seen that solution. Very helpful in case of loop unrolling. But now i'm looking for the code motion - taking expression outside loop and sotring it to a new variable.